# Exercise 11.5 from Atiyah-MacDonald: Hilbert-Serre theorem and Grothendieck group

Tags: commutative-algebra

I don't understand Exercise 11.5 of Atiyah & MacDonald, which demands one elaborate upon or rephrase the Hilbert–Serre Theorem (11.1) in terms of the Grothendieck group $K(A_0)$.

Here's the set-up in more detail. $A$ is a commutative Noetherian graded ring, finitely generated as an algebra over its degree-$0$ summand $A_0$ by finitely many elements $x_j$ of degrees $k_j > 0$. $\lambda$ is some additive function from the class of finitely generated $A_0$-modules to the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ — no field is presumed involved, so $\lambda$ is not assumed to be dimension.

For a finitely generated graded $A$-module $M$, the *Poincaré series* of $M$ with respect to $\lambda$ is the power series

$$P_\lambda(M,t) := \sum \lambda(M_n) t^n \in \mathbb{Z}[[t]].$$

If we write $q(t) = \prod (1 - t^{k_j})$ and compute the reciprocal $q^{-1}$ of $q$ in the power series ring $\mathbb{Z}[[t]]$, then the theorem is that

$$P_\lambda(M,t) \in q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}[t] \subset \mathbb{Z}[[t]];$$

that is, the Poincaré series is actually just a polynomial times the reciprocal of $q$.

Under the book's definition, the *Grothendieck group* $K(A_0)$ is the quotient of the free abelian group on the isomorphism classes of finitely generated $A_0$-modules by the subgroup generated by all elements $[N] - [M] + [P]$ for short exact sequences $0 \to N \to M \to P \to 0$ of such modules. No grading is invoked in this definition, and all finitely generated modules are used as generators, not merely projective or flat ones.

The question, again, is how to reformulate the result about $P_\lambda(M,t)$ in terms of $K(A_0)$.

---

My attempts to say something meaningful, which have turned out to be rather inadequate, follow.

First, if we define $K_{\mathrm{gr}}(A)$ to be the *graded* Grothendieck group of $A$, meaning we only admit isomorphism classes of *graded* $A$-modules as generators in the preceding definition and *degree-preserving* $A$-module homomorphisms in the exact sequences we use to generate the subgroup we quotient by, then it seems clear, using additivity of $\lambda$ on the summands $M_i$, that $M \mapsto P_\lambda(M,t)$ induces a homomorphism of additive groups $K_{\mathrm{gr}}(A) \to \mathbb{Z}[[t]]$ with values in the same subgroup $q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}[t]$ as before.

Further, one can pass from additive $\mathbb{Z}$-valued functions $\lambda$ on the class of finitely generated $A_0$-modules to group homomorphisms $l\colon K(A_0) \to \mathbb{Z}$, and say that for any such $l$, one can define an analogous homomorphism $Q_l(-,t)\colon K_{\mathrm{gr}}(A) \to \mathbb{Z}[[t]]$, with image as before.

This reformulation hardly seems enlightening, though. If we make $l$ a variable in this expression too, we get a function

$$Q\colon \mathrm{Hom}\big(K(A_0),\mathbb{Z}\big) \times K_{\mathrm{gr}}(A) \to q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}[t] \subset \mathbb{Z}[[t]].$$

This looks a little different than the original, but is not particularly more interesting.

Finally, another thing we can do is to factor all the $P_\lambda$ or $Q_l$ through the additive group $K(A_0)[[t]]$ to get a sort of "universal" Poincaré series, and note that for all 
$l \in \mathrm{Hom}\big(K(A_0),\mathbb{Z}\big)$, the image is contained in (well, I believe it 
*is*) $q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}[t]$. I would like to be able to lift the result about the image up to $K(A_0)[[t]]$, but since $K(A_0)$ doesn't usually have a ring structure, multiplication and hence $q^{-1}$ are not apparently defined in $K(A_0)[[t]]$. We can also make $l$ a variable as before.

I have trouble believing that the intended answer could be something so insubstantial.

Now, looking in Eisenbud, I did find that in the case where $A$ is a polynomial ring over a field $k$ and $\lambda = \dim_k$, the graded Poincaré series, if I am rephrasing correctly, gives an isomorphism from $K_{\mathrm{gr}}(A)$ to $q^{-1} \mathbb{Z}[t]$ (and hence implies an isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}[t]$). That seems substantive enough. However, I don't see how hypotheses on $A$ and $\lambda$ as broad as ours could yield anything similarly interesting.

---

So what do you suppose they are looking for here?

Comment: I remember thinking about this exercise a pretty long time and I think all they mean is the (somehow unspectacular) following. Every homomorphism $K(A_0)\to\mathbb{Z}$ gives rise to an additive function $\lambda$, so you can define $P_\lambda$ for such homomorphisms and conclude that, again, $P_\lambda\in q^{-1}\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Comment: Thank you.

Speaking of unspectacular, is the amount of response to this question over this length of time typical for this site? 

Do you suppose I've done something wrong in formulating, titling, or submitting this question? Or is it perhaps inherently just not a very appealing one? 

I've been checking pretty regularly here and am wondering what I could have done wrong.

Comment: Dear @jdc, no, I don't think so. I actually liked your question and how extensive you presented your ideas. My response may have caused some idleness, but I rather think that simply none of the users reading the question got a better idea (so far). However, supposed my idea is correct, it would be interesting to see if this has any $K$-theoretic consequences. Maybe someone knows some and takes the time to write an expanded answer?

Comment: Dear @Ben A., thank you for liking it. My worry is that maybe too few (sixty-one, possibly counting myself multiple times, if the software does that) people read it to begin with. It would be great if someone who knows more finds this and could give an expanded answer.

Comment: @navigetor23: 

Thank you, I will do that.

Comment: Are you upset I haven't said something more? Or maybe suggesting that once I've completed reading the paper, I should post what I find as solution myself? I'm not really sure how to interpret this. Anyway, I haven't gotten very far in the paper yet. It looks like he works over fields, which is a hypothesis beyond than I had originally hoped for, but I'll let you know what I think later, okay?

Comment: Am I looking upset? Well, I simply wanted to know if my reference was helpful, but it seems (not and) you are thinking too far.

Comment: Dear @navigetor23 (and jdc of course), I followed your suggestion too and the forwarding to their reference for *why it's natural to consider K-groups*, i.e. Fraser, *Multiplicities and Grothendieck Groups*. There I read very related and interesting stuff, but I can't read an explicit answer to the question (the way I thought of it) from it. If the aim of the exercise actually simply is to make the reader think about it (rather than just to rephrase a theorem), your reference may help to reach a (subjectively) satisfactory 'answer', i.e. to come to an end.

Comment: That's exactly what I've thought.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response; due to a large storm, I was suffering a power outage. So, the system is giving me a notification that says the following: "This question had a bounty worth +50 reputation from jdc that ended 3 hours ago; you have 20 hours to award the bounty." The bounty apparently must go to navigetor23, as his/her reference was the closest thing to an answer &mdash; so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I missed the deadline. There goes the imaginary money. I hope you don't feel your effort has been wasted. I am hesitant to post on MathOverflow, as the last two things I posted on there were far, far below the intended level of the site (one, upon inspection, too ill-formulated to even be answered), and I was quite embarrassed when I realized how seriously inappropriate they had been. That they weren't closed was, I think, merely out of politeness. I actually doubt I could even come up with a question relevant to that site.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a true answer, but I think it could be useful: the paper of W. Smoke  [*Dimension and Multiplicity for Graded Algebras*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869372900142) treats the case where $A_0$ is a field and obtains a homomorphism $\chi_R$ of $\mathbb{Z}[t]$-modules from $K_{\text{gr}}(A)$ to $\mathbb{Z}[[t]]$. Furthermore, if any finitely generated $A$-graded module have a finite graded free resolution, then $\chi_R$ is an isomorphism from $K_{\text{gr}}(A)$ to $\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Comment: Is this in Smoke? I don't seem to see it. Anyway, it generalizes the exercise in Eisenbud (19.15), where your $A$ is a finitely generated polynomial ring over a field. Thank you for this.

Comment: Well, if isn't there surely it is in this [Smoke](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183532082).